# SmtpClient sending without authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, authentication, smtpclient

I am sending emails to our clients from Java. And there is no any authentication for our SMTP. So I use the following code in Java to send it without authentication:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
Session session;
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
```

This code works fine for sending emails from Java. But I want to send emails using ASP.NET and C#. But I am unable to send it. For sending it using C# I am using the following code:

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "<My smtp.Host>";
smtp.EnableSsl = false;
smtp.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.Send(message);
```

But it gives me the following error:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
>   authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Relaying not allowed: `<Here email address of To>`

How to send it without authentication?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From Msdn. `If the UseDefaultCredentials property is set to false and the Credentials property has not been set, then mail is sent to the server anonymously.`

Comment: I don't get it. Which property should I set to send it without authentication?

Comment: You remove `smtp.Credentials = ...` completely, and set `UseDefaultCredentials` to false.

Comment: Then your server disallows relaying, which means only the local server can send mail, or only a known user.